# Is detecting an object based on its edge possible with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-recognition

I am working on a project for recognizing an object from 3D space (video feed) given a sample of its edge (outline).

I tried using templates and trying to detect the object after converting the feed to Canny mode:

```
sample1 = cv2.imread('./canny detection/sample2.png')
sample1 = cv2.cvtColor(sample1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
sample1 = cv2.Canny(sample1, 100, 150)

template = cv2.imread('./canny detection/cube1.png')
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 100, 150)

threshold = 0.7

w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(sample1, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
detected = 0
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    if detected < 1:
        cv2.rectangle(sample1, pt, (pt[0]+w, pt[1]+h), (50,100,255), 5)
        detected = detected + 1
        print('detected')

cv2.imshow('sample1', sample1)
cv2.imshow('template', template)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but this was no use. I lowered the threshold to 5 and from that point it was pointless. I also tried matching the image in a video feed, that didnt work either.

Comment: If anyone is still looking at this question, I found the mistake. I can't use template based recognition in canny mode. I have resorted to using contures and in my opinion they are much more accurate.